# How to reuse CustomAction in InstallExecuteSequence

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a `CustomAction` that modifies a json file with a key value. I would like to use this in a similar way to `util:XmlFile`. The best I have come up with is this:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="PropertySetForModifyJson" After="CostFinalize" />
  <Custom Action="ModifyCentralJsonCustomAction" After="PropertySetForModifyJson" />
  <Custom Action="Property2SetForModifyJson" After="CostFinalize" />
  <Custom Action="ModifyCentralJsonCustomAction" After="Property2SetForModifyJson" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

where the actions are set up as:

```
<CustomAction Id='ModifyCentralAppSettingsJsonCustomAction' BinaryKey="InstallerCustomActions" DllEntry="ModifyCentralJson" Execute='immediate' Return='check'/>

<CustomAction Id='PropertySetForModifyJson' Property="CustomActionData" Value="Key=foo;Value=bar;"/>
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to reuse the `DllEntry` action as it is flagged as a duplicate. Is there any way to reuse this common entry point? Or maybe another solution?

Answer (score 0):

A custom action can be scheduled at most once but you can have custom actions that are identical except for their `Id` -- that's what causes duplication errors. Typically, if you have a lot of data, a single immediate custom action is driven by the data in custom tables and schedules as many invocations of deferred custom actions as needed.